# Log message missing for 1 minute in log file

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j

This is about a Spring boot web application(**App1**) which is running in a Linux server (DEV environment).
App1 is using Log4j v1 to write logs into a file.

App1 exposes a **REST endpoint** which is called by App2 ( maintained by another team and I have no idea about that application).

App2 team reported http 500 error when calling App1.

I checked the logs of App1 and **logs are missing for 1 minute** duration as below.

[image]

App1 threw **http 500 error** during above 1 minute gap.

I checked with **network team and they confirmed that there is no CPU or Memory issues** during this period in this Linux Server.

This happened 2 or 3 times in last 3 months.

Is there any clue about what are the probable causes for this kind of behavior?

Comment: Just a guess among others : maybe a rolling appender that could take time.

Comment: Rolling appender is running once per day , midnight 12 am, not during above mentioned time.

Comment: Well, what's the monitoring period for cpu, memory? It could be missing the problem. Look at system logs also (journalctl and/or /var/log/*.

Comment: Maybe an NTP sync?